# Insufficient access on cross reference entity

Tags: apex, trigger

While doing after update trigger I am getting the insufficient error.
Requirement: in my scenario, record x can b created by admin and manager. but auditor can create a y record from x. x and y are in a parent-child relationship. while saving record x, the parent owner id will be changed to rep. I am sharing the y record when updating status.This record needs to be shared to CreatedBy of X record.

```
public class USRetail_CRATriggerHandler {
    public static void shareCoachingReportAuditRec(List<ID> ids) 
    {
    List<Coaching_Report_Audit__Share> craList=new List<Coaching_Report_Audit__Share>();
    List<Coaching_Report_Audit__c> coachingreportaudits=[select id,Coaching_Report__r.createdByid from Coaching_Report_Audit__c where id=:ids];
    for(Coaching_Report_Audit__c cra:coachingreportaudits){
        Coaching_Report_Audit__Share crashare=new Coaching_Report_Audit__Share();
        crashare.ParentId=cra.Id;
        crashare.RowCause='Manual';
        crashare.UserOrGroupId=cra.Coaching_Report__r.createdByid;        
        crashare.AccessLevel='Edit';
        craList.add(crashare);
    }
    insert craList;
    //system.debug('Test------>'+craList);
}
}
```

Error

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY,:
>   Class.USRetail_CRATriggerHandler.shareCoachingReportAuditRec: line 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your custom object is related to parent as Master Details relationship, you can not have a sharing object. It will be determined by the parent's sharing setting.

Or

If that user has already had a sharing access on that record, this error will be thrown.
try using 
Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(crashare,false);
to avoid the error on record saving.